# Proof using matrices, when does $XA=XB$ imply $A=B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I really need help about this fact regarding proofs that use matrices.

When a property like $XA=XB$ is valid $\forall X$ is it possible to conclude that $A=B$? (I'm supposing a general case, where $X$ is not necessarily square or invertible)

For example to determine the conditions for which an endomorphism $f$ (with associated matrix $A$) is self-adjoint with respect to a bilinear simmetric form $\phi$  (with associated matrix $B$)
I impose

$\phi(f(\vec{x}),\vec{y})=\phi(\vec{x},f(\vec{y}))$

$(A X)^{T} B Y =X^{T} B AY$

$X^{T} A^{T}B Y= X^{T} B AY$

And this must be true $\forall X$ and $\forall Y$

So I conclude that $A^{T}B=BA$

Is this the reason why I can get to the conclusion?

I saw very similar things in several other proofs and I wonder what are the criteria for which is right to conclude that two matrices are equal from a property involving a matrix product.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: If you want it true for all $X$, then it must be true when $X$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: No, if $X$ is not invertible, you could let $X =0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really stated what kind of thing $X$ is, but if it's allowed to be any matrix of a given shape, then yes, it implies $A=B$.
$XA = XB$ is equivalent to $X (A - B) = 0$. For any vector $v \ne 0$ you could take some $X$ such that $X v \ne 0$.  Thus the range of $A-B$ can't contain any nonzero vector, and that means $A-B=0$.

Comment: What if $X = 0$? Then $A\neq B$ necessary.

Comment: @Nameless You want it *for all $X$*

Comment: @egreg, ah okay I misread OP's intentions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm sorry $X$ is a matrix without a particular shape, for example it contains the coordinates of a general vector with respect to a general basis. Thanks a lot for this answer! I did not understand completely the passage where the vector $v$ is used, is $v=A-B$ in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y vary over the standard basis vecors then the matrices are identical component by component.